# angular 2 animation is not working as expected

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular 2 rc6 and I would like to have page transitions based on the route path. I am applying the following animation on two paths (as a test). I just want to animate the opacity and nothing else. But no matter what I do, I am unable to stop the page from translating on Y axis. The only option that I found which seemed to work is using `style.position: absolute` for host. I don't want to use that as that screws the position of all the elements on the page. I have also tried having just `opactiy` without the `transform`. That didn't work either.

```
   host: {
     '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
     '[style.display]': "'block'"
  },
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [

      transition('void => *', [
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translatey(0)'}),
        animate('0.2s')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate('0.2s', style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translatey(0)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

I am sure i am missing something here. not quite sure what? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Not yet. When I do, I will definitely update it here.

Answer (score 0):

1) As you can see you spelled transteY incorrectly the value of transform X or Y.

```
style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translatey(0)'}),
```

Should be **uppercase** like so:

```
style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(0)'}),
```

2) Another thing I see in your code is that you binded your animation selector like so: `[@routeAnimation]': 'true'` if you used this selector exactly like this on your html you could never turn it on by toggling a boolean for example, try using a boolean like `isMovingY = 'false'` and place it in the selector like so `[@routeAnimation]': isMovingY` now when you toggle it with a click for example it could activate the "enter" / "leave" states you declared in the animation.